# try to generate multiple arrays with random numbers but get the same array every time

Tags: visual-c++, random

I was trying to make a simulation of randomly picking number from 1-36, and to see how many time do I need to pick all the different 36 number. If I picked total of 10 duplicated number I can pick a number that has not been picked, and recount duplication.
Anyway, my code works fine if I only create one array contains random numbers. But I add a for loop outside of the whole process and repeat it 100 times in order to find out on average how many time do I need. And the code create 100 of same arrays.

```
    #include "iostream"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "time.h"

    using namespace std;

    class Lottery
    {
    private:
        int PickNonExistingNum()//pick a number that's not in num
        {   
            int pick;   
            pick = RandomNumber();
            for (int m = 0; m < 36; m++)
            {
                if (pick == num[m])
                {
                    pick = RandomNumber();
                    m = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return pick;
        }

    public:
        int check;
        int TimeOfPicking = 0;      //how many time we pick a number
        int num[36] = { 0 };        //array contains all the number
        bool same = false;          //flag that indicates consistency
        int accum = 0;              //how many time we pick a same number, when reach 10 we pick again
        bool IsRandomSeeded = false;

        int i = 0;                  //used to change i value in for loop of main loop

        int RandomNumber()//generate a number from 1 to 36
        {
            int number;
            number = rand() % 36 + 1;
            return number;
        }

        bool CheckExistingNum()
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 36; k++)
            {
                if (check == num[k])
                {
                    if (accum < 10)//add 1 to accum each time when there's a same number
                    {
                        i--;
                        accum++;
                        same = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (accum == 10)//pick again when accum reach 10
                    {
                        num[i] = DoubleCheckPick(PickNonExistingNum());
                        accum = 0;
                        same = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return same;
        }

        void Picking()
        {
            for (i; i < 36; i++)//finish the loop when player had picked all 36 numbers
            {
                check = RandomNumber();//give check a random value between 1 and 36
                TimeOfPicking++;    //add 1 time to the total time of picking
                same = false;       //set flag to false

                if (!CheckExistingNum())//give checked value to num if there's no same number
                {
                    num[i] = check;
                }
            }

            cout << "Pick " << TimeOfPicking << " time" << endl;//show results
            cout << "the numbers are:" << endl;
            for (int m = 0; m < 36; m++)
            {
                cout << num[m] << ", ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        bool DoubleCheck()
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 36; m++)
            {
                for (int k = m + 1; k < 36; k++)
                {
                    if (num[m] == num[k])
                    {
                        cout << "there's a same number: " << num[m] << endl << endl;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "no same number" << endl << endl;
            return true;
        }

        int DoubleCheckPick(int check)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 36; m++)
            {
                if (check == num[m])
                {
                    check = PickNonExistingNum();
                    m = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return check;
        }

        void reset()//reset all the value for multiple process
        {
            int TimeOfPicking = 0;      //how many time we pick a number
            int num[36] = { 0 };        //array contains all the number
            int same = false;           //flag that indicates consistency
            int accum = 0;              //how many time we pick a same number, when reach 10 we pick again
            int check = 0;

            int i = 0;                  //used to change i value in for loop of main loop
        }

    };


    int main()
    {   
        Lottery Num;

        //int t = 0;

        srand(time(NULL));              //set random generator

        int PickingTime[100] = { 0 };//an array contains all 100 times of data
        double sum = 0;              //the sum of all the data

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)//run the program 100 times
        {
            cout << "the " << i + 1 << " process" << endl;

            int wait = clock();
            while (clock() <= (wait + 1000));//delay for 3000 unit time 

            Num.reset();
            Num.Picking();
            if (!Num.DoubleCheck())//if there's a same number
            {
                cout << "fail process" << endl;
                i--;            //redo the process
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                PickingTime[i] = Num.TimeOfPicking;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sum += PickingTime[i];
        }

        cout << "the average picking time in 100 test is: " << sum / 100 << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

and the result looks like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8W8Y.png)
all the arrays are the same. I guess it might be the rand() problem, but I can't find any solution that will work.

Comment: this is most likely because of cycle. Your random number generator has the cycle of 36. So, it is tending to repeat itself. you better try changing the cycle

Comment: but it should be a different sequence of number every time i call rand(), and each time i run the program the arrays are different then last time but same for each other.

Comment: It has nothing to do with random number generator - you have used `rand()` correctly - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reset()` function did not actually reset the class variables - it defined new local ones. So the subsequent calls to Picking() didn't do anything for `i` was already `36`. Change it to the following:

```
void reset()//reset all the value for multiple process
{
    TimeOfPicking = 0;      //how many time we pick a number
    //int num[36] = { 0 };  //No need to reset the array - it will be overriden in the later invocation of Picking()
    same = false;           //flag that indicates consistency
    accum = 0;              //how many time we pick a same number, when reach 10 we pick again
    check = 0;

    i = 0;                  //used to change i value in for loop of main loop
}
```

And you get different number sequences each time.

Note that your `CheckExistingNum()` must be fixed too for this to work - change `for (int k = 0; k < 36; k++)` to `for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)` to only check the numbers generated in the current loop, not old ones. This is required because we don't reset `num` in `reset()` (to set it to all zero anywhere other than initialization, you must use a loop or `memset()`). And it also make your program faster.

After the 2 fixes, I got the following output,

```
......
the 98 process
Pick 76 time
the numbers are:
26, 9, 4, 36, 32, 12, 16, 7, 17, 33, 1, 10, 18, 2, 23, 21, 28, 29, 30, 25, 8, 34, 27, 31, 14, 24, 11, 20, 6, 22, 3, 15, 19, 5, 13, 26,
there's a same number: 26

fail process
the 98 process
Pick 76 time
the numbers are:
17, 3, 15, 7, 31, 12, 26, 24, 9, 13, 4, 32, 29, 11, 20, 14, 23, 1, 33, 18, 8, 27, 21, 19, 25, 6, 30, 36, 2, 5, 28, 34, 22, 35, 16, 10,
no same number

the 99 process
Pick 106 time
the numbers are:
10, 11, 9, 28, 36, 15, 18, 8, 13, 34, 30, 3, 12, 21, 16, 1, 2, 27, 19, 23, 17, 5, 20, 14, 4, 25, 6, 29, 7, 22, 33, 26, 32, 24, 31, 35,
no same number

the 100 process
Pick 106 time
the numbers are:
15, 23, 22, 11, 5, 35, 2, 26, 21, 4, 3, 33, 28, 19, 1, 14, 7, 29, 24, 32, 8, 12, 13, 27, 10, 17, 34, 18, 16, 6, 25, 20, 31, 36, 30, 9,
no same number
```

Try it out! You could further optimize the program, which is left as an exercise. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried and it works! But other than this, I'm also curious about why are there always two same number at the start and the end of an array? Is it something to do with my code's structure?

Comment: Add `printf`'s in each function or learn to use breakpoints (I saw your `visual-c++` tag - Visual Studio really made debugging enjoyable, you should give it a shot). Take your time and the cause's gonna be unveiled. Happy debugging!